# preserving both `this` references when using jQuery proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, and I use `$.proxy` to remain in context when attaching events to functions. Something like this:

```
function myPlugin(element) {
    this.element = $(element);
}

$.extend(myPlugin.prototype, {
    init: function() {
        this.btns = this.element.find('.control-btns');
        this.register_events();
    },

    register_events: function() {
        this.btns
            .off('click.myplugin')
            .on('click.myplugin', $.proxy(this.foo, this));                   
    },

    foo: function(e) {
        this.bar();
        var btnClicked = $(e.target);
    },

    bar: function() {
        // some code here
    }
});
```

As you can see, when running `foo` I need to have the right context for `this` in order to be able to call the `bar` function (it's just for the example, I do more than call one specific function).

However, **I also need the other** `this` **- the one representing the button being clicked**. I thought `e.target` will be enough, but it turns out that it catches the thing that was clicked, not the element with the event listener - i.e. if my button has some inner area (say a span), clicking it will propagate, but then `e.target` will point to the `<span>` instead of the `<button>`. I made a [small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/1fxej0ra/) showing the problem.

How can I pass the correct `this` context, without losing the one I would've gotten otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `target` you need the [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget). `currentTarget` is the element you attached the event handler.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1fxej0ra/2/)